# Car repossessed from fraudulent loan

Tags: criminal-law, fraud

My family member's son in law took out a loan in the family member's name using the family member's car as collateral. No payments were made on the loan. The car was repossessed after the loan defaulted. The auto loan was issued in Van Nuys, California.

A police report was created in Broward County, Florida. The loan company refuses to return the vehicle without full payment of the loan and is threatening to charge more over time.

If the loan were paid, would that impact the criminal fraud investigation in any way? Will the defaulted loan be removed from my family member's credit report once the criminal case is complete? Has anyone been through anything similar that could provide a time frame for all of this to shake out?

Comment: What jurisdiction is this happening in?

Comment: The loan was issued in Van Nuys, California. The police report was created in Broward County, Florida.

Comment: Where did the repossession physically take place? which state? Did the lender make any attempt to confirm that the son actually owned the car?

Comment: @DavidSiegel The repossession took place in Broward County, Florida. The lender made copies of the drivers license and title for the vehicle. I don't believe any other attempts were made to verify ownership.